# How to force BE users to paste as plain text in TYPO3 6.x?

Tags: editor, typo3, paste, rte, tsconfig

CMS users tend to paste anything into CMS text editors. To prevent website destruction - and as log as there's no non-wysiwyg editor (like [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)) for TYPO3, I would like to as least have some good old "force plain text paste" in place.

TYPO3's RTE has a button "pastetoggle, pastebehaviour, pasteastext". But I haven't managed to configure it so it's always active.

Also, there's an extension [ad_rtepasteplain](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ad_rtepasteplain), but it produced no result in TYPO3 6.1.

Is there a usable way to implement paste-as-plain-text for TYPO3 6.x?

[EDIT]
I found (for user TSConfig)

- setup.default.rteCleanPasteBehaviour
- setup.override.rteCleanPasteBehaviour

as well as (for page TSConfig)

- buttons.pastetoggle.setActiveOnRteOpen
- buttons.pastetoggle.hidden

... none of which I got running yet. If that's the way to go: is there a working tutorial?

Comment: I found setup.default.rteCleanPasteBehaviour and setup.override.rteCleanPasteBehaviour for user TSConfig as well as buttons.pastetoggle.setActiveOnRteOpen and buttons.pastetoggle.hidden for page TSConfig - none of which I got running yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. This is my current setup

```
RTE.default {
  enableWordClean = 1
  removeTrailingBR = 1
  removeComments = 1
  removeTags = center, font, o:p, sdfield, u
  removeTagsAndContents = link, meta, script, style, title  

  hidePStyleItems = h5,h6,pre,address,div

  // buttons
  showButtons =  chMode, formatblock, insertcharacter, removeformat, unorderedlist, orderedlist, outdent, indent, link, copy, cut, paste,  showhelp, about,line, bold,pastetoggle, pastebehaviour, pasteastext

 buttons.pastetoggle.setActiveOnRteOpen = 1
 buttons.pastetoggle.hidden = 1

}
```

as well as setup.override.rteCleanPasteBehaviour=pasteStructure or plainText in user TSConfig